# Rails 6 - How to use the old sprocket assets pipeline instead of webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know if its possible to use the old sprocket pipeline setup in Rails 6? I've read somewhere that it's possible to use it instead of the new webpacker pipeline, but i can't find the source where i've read that.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Greetings!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well this is how i did it

```
rails new app-name --skip-webpack-install --skip-javascript
```

`--skip-webpack-install` prevents the generator from running rails webpacker:install.

`--skip-javascript` drops the webpacker gem from the Gemfile.

now in rails 6 **app/assets/javascripts** doesn't exists so you will have to create it yourself

Then, create **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** and add the following lines to it

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Next, open **app/assets/config/manifest.js** and add the following line in the end

```
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
```

Finally, open your application layout (**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**) remove the `javascript_pack_tag` and add the following line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I already have used --skip-webpack and --skip-javascript but wasn't sure about it since it still gave me the new folder structure! Thanks for letting me knowing!